# Why can't I use "this" inside the inner function?

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I am new to JavaScript. I have the following script working,

```
var navRef = this.navigator;
function onSearch( templateName) {
    navRef.onSearch();
}
```

but not the one below and I am trying to understand why? Any help is appreciated. (navigator is sent as an argument to this object).

```
function onSearch( templateName) {
    this.navigator.onSearch();
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer until you show us how you call `onSearch` and where you define your code. I suggest you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: [This MDN arcticle about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/) on the `this` keyword. Essentially, `this` is used within a function to refer to the context in which that function is executed. When the function in question is called as a method on an object, `this` refers to that object. When the function is called in the global scope and has no instance to refer to, `this` refers to the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

'this' points to different objects in the two cases.  In the first case 'this' most likely refers to the windows object that has navigator as a property.  In the second case 'this', most likely, refers to whatever object invoked the function.  It's hard to be exact since you didn't give the context.  But this should be enough to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on [javascript scopes](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).  In the first example the 'this' is referencing the current scope (that has the navigator property).  In your second example, the 'this' is actually referencing the current function scope it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has lexical scope so variables (like your `navRef`) can be used inside inner functions

```
var navRef = this.navigator;
function onSearch(){
    navRef.onShow();
}
```

**the `this` "variable", however, is an evil exception**. Each function gets its own `this` (and the value it has [depends on how the function was called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) so if you want to access an outer `this` (or one of its properties) you need to use an intermediate variable:

```
var that = this;
function onSearch(){
    that.navigator.onSearch();
}
```